# Subscript out of range when trying to get number of entries in column

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm new to VBA and I've come across an error that doesn't make sense to me. I'm creating a macro that will go inside a workbook and take all the entries in the first column and create an email using the entries as email addresses. This is my code:

```
Public Sub emailList()
   'Setting up the Excel variables.
   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim olMailItm As Object
   Dim iCounter As Integer
   Dim Dest As Variant
   Dim SDest As String

   'Create the Outlook application and the empty email.
   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)

   'Using the email, add multiple recipients, using a list of addresses in column A.
   With olMailItm
       SDest = ""
       For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets(1).Columns(1))
           If SDest = "" Then
               SDest = Cells(iCounter, 1).Value
           Else
               SDest = SDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 1).Value
           End If
       Next iCounter

    'Do additional formatting on the BCC and Subject lines, add the body text from the spreadsheet, and send.
       .BCC = SDest
       .Subject = "FYI"
       .Body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes(1).Text
       .Send
   End With

   'Clean up the Outlook application.
   Set olMailItm = Nothing
   Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

The line that says:

```
For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Book1.xls").Sheets(1).Columns(1))
```

is throwing a Subscript Out Of Range error but i have three entries in column 1 so I dont see why it's throwing an out of bounds error.

Comment: Could mean you don't have a workbook with that exact name...

Comment: I do though. I have it saved in my Documents folder, is that a problem?

Comment: is the workbook open when you run this code? If not, you need to open it first. It doesn't matter where it's saved so long as its open.

Comment: Paste this `Workbooks("Book1.xls").Activate` into the Immediate pane in the VB editor and hit enter - what happens ?

Comment: I also have it opened. I opened excel before outlook and vice versa but it's still not working

Comment: @TimWilliams Immediate pane? I'm editing this in outlook

Comment: Outlook doesn't know anything about `Worksheetfunction` or `Workbooks`...

Comment: @TimWilliams I pasted the code into my code and it's throwing a Subscript out of range error

Comment: "I'm creating a macro that will go inside a workbook" - make your mind up: are you editing this code in Excel, or in Outlook?  It *looks* like it belongs in Excel.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added in the reference Microsoft Excel Objects library. Do i have to do more for Worksheetfunction and Workbooks to work?

Comment: @TimWilliams Why would it belong in excel? The macro works with outlook and excel

Comment: Nowhere in your code do you actually create a reference to Excel - it's not enough to add the reference in the VBproject, you actually need an instance of excel to work with.   http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/408511-controlling-excel-through-outlook-visual-basic-applications-range-pasting-problems.html

Comment: @TimWilliams Ok i understand you now. I created an outlook object which is why it "looks" like it belongs in excel. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try this loop instead, assuming the email addresses start at row 2. Set up excel objects first

```
'setup excel objects
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\Book1.xlsx")
Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
WB.Activate

'loop through ColA to merge email addresses
Dim last As Long
last = WS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
SDest = ""
For i = 2 To last
    SDest = SDest + Range("A" & i).Value & ";"
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the error and got it working (Thank you Tim). I did not add an excel object and the file name was incorrect which is why it kept throwing the out of bounds error. This is my new code:

```
Public Sub emailList()
   'Setting up the Excel variables.
   Dim olApp As Object
   Dim olMailItm As Object
   Dim iCounter As Integer
   Dim Dest As Variant
   Dim SDest As String
   Dim Excel As Object

   'Create the Outlook application and the empty email.
   Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)

      'Create excel object.
   Set Excel = CreateObject("excel.application")
   Excel.Visible = True
   Excel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\Deryl Lam\Documents\Book1.xlsx")
   Excel.Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Activate

   'Using the email, add multiple recipients, using a list of addresses in column A.
   With olMailItm
       SDest = ""
       For iCounter = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(1).Columns(1))
           If SDest = "" Then
               SDest = Cells(iCounter, 1).Value
           Else
               SDest = SDest & ";" & Cells(iCounter, 1).Value
           End If
       Next iCounter

    'Do additional formatting on the BCC and Subject lines, add the body text from the spreadsheet, and send.
       .BCC = SDest
       .Subject = "FYI"
       .Body = ActiveSheet.TextBoxes(1).Text
       .Send
   End With

   'Clean up the Outlook application.
   Set olMailItm = Nothing
   Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```